# Call specific function on PHP from AJAX with newform image

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have problem pass data from selected file (image)

i will move the image to localhost directory

here my simple code

```
function uploadFile(){
  event.preventDefault();
  var input = document.getElementById("uploadImage");
  file = input.files[0];
  if(file != undefined){
    formData= new FormData();
    if(!!file.type.match(/image.*/)){
      formData.append("image", file);
     
      $.ajax({
        url: "service.php?aksi=A",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert('data);
        }
      });
    }else{
      alert('Not a valid image!');
    }
  }else{
    alert('Input something!');
  }
}
```

here my simple html code

```
 <input type="file" required="" id="uploadImage" name="gambar" >
                       
<button id="gantiphoto"  name="submit" onclick="uploadFile()" class="btn btn-default">Upload </button>
```

and call it to specific php function

```
if ($_POST["aksi"]=="A"){
    
$dir = "asset/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $dir. $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

}
elseif ($_POST["aksi"]=="B"){
    
}
```

i try

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "service.php?aksi=A",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert('data);
        }
      });
```

and

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "service.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "aksi=A"+formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert('data);
        }
      });
```

but the response still
Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\rutela\service.php on line 166
or

Notice: Undefined index: aksi in C:\xampp\htdocs\rutela\service.php on line 7

i still dont understand how to pass this image file,. im success with text but cant solve this image pass data

im appreciate ur answer, im just newbie in ajax

Comment: Please use php `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to check. As your url in main example `url: "service.php?aksi=A",` contains GET string, may be your ajax is GETing instead of POSTing.
BTW, `alert('data);` in `success` callback of `$.ajax` has typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Add One More formData Filed

```
formData.append("aksi", "A");
```

Also Change Url to This

> service.php
> After This You Can Check Like

```
if($_POST['aksi'] == "A"){
$dir = "asset/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $dir. $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
}
else if($_POST['aksi'] == "B")
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things I might change to make this work:

```
<script>
function submitForm()
{
    // Set error state a true
    var valid   =   false;
    // Init
    var data1 = new FormData();
    // Loop files
    $.each($('input[type="file"]')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        // If the file is good
        if(!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
            // Update status to valid
            valid   =   true;
            // Add file
            data1.append(i, file);
        }
    });
    // Do the ajax
    if(!valid) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "service.php?aksi=A",
            type: "POST",
            data: data1,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#response').html(response);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        alert('Incorrect file type');
    }
}
</script>

<div id="response"></div>
<input type="file" required="" id="uploadImage" name="gambar" >                   
<button id="gantiphoto"  name="submit" onclick="submitForm()" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
```

In your PHP you should first try a test to make sure but I would switch to `$_GET` here not `$_POST`:

```
// ****** START TEST ******//

// If you do a test, you can see what is being sent so it will help you
// narrow down where it's going wrong
echo '<pre>'.print_r([
    $_POST,
    $_GET,
    $_FILES
], 1).'</pre>';

// ****** START ACTUAL CODE ******//

// Stop if this is not set
if(empty($_GET["aksi"]))
    die('aksi is a required parameter.');
// Switch to GET here
switch($_GET["aksi"]) {
    case('A'):
        if(empty($_FILES))
            die('Invalid image.');
        $dir = "asset/";
        // I haven't checked, but I think these keys are numeric now
        // The test above should tell you what they are exactly
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES[0]["tmp_name"], $dir. $_FILES[0]["name"]);
        break;
    case('B'):
        // do stuff
}
```